# Why is arrow function sent as a parameter when it simply returns the value it takes as is?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I am learning React using the following [tutorial](https://survivejs.com/react/implementing-kanban/react-and-flux/).

It also teaches to use Alt as a state management library and my question is related to the `connect` method syntax. I am not explaining the problem in detail as I believe my question is only related to understanding the syntax.

I understand that here connect passes comma separated parameters as props to the component App. I however do not understand the first parameter.

The arrow functions I have come across all use `{}` after `=>` such as `() => {}`, where parameters will be in `()` and body of the function will be in `{}`

My understanding of `({lanes}) => ({lanes})` is that this is a function that takes an array of objects named lanes and returns the same array .The code snippet is as below:

```
export default connect(({lanes}) => ({lanes}), {
    LaneActions
})(App)
```

My questions are:

1. Am I right that the first parameter is indeed a function?
2. is lanes enclosed in `{}` to specify it's an array?  If no, what does it represent?
3. If 1. is right, why pass a function that passes the parameter as is. Why not write connect as `connect(lanes,LaneActions)(App)` or `connect({lanes},LaneActions)(App)`
   Would enclosing lanes in `{}` make a difference and what is it?
4. If 1. is wrong please explain what the first parameter means.

Comment: Please help me make the question better if you want to downvote.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I actually did my best to follow those guidelines. Thank you.

Comment: Advice: don't ask six separate questions in one question. Find a way to summarize what you're looking for as one concise question.

Comment: 1 through 4 seem reasonable to ask in the same question, since they're fundamentally all related to "what is this doing, and why?". I'd recommend asking 5 and 6 as new questions, since those are very broad.

Comment: @EthanKaminski i'm not really sure () => {} and () => ()  are even  related for me to ask someone to compare them which is why I thought 5 and 6 fit here. If someone answers this question even very briefly it will give me a better idea of what they mean and then for more clarity I could ask a new question.

Comment: @SamHanley I have tried to make it concise but I am afraid that will not give me clear answers. To me, they only seem to be sub parts of one question that I've written so to get very specific answers.Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, that is indeed an arrow function.
2. No, that is *not* an "array" in JS (although if you've used PHP, you might mistakenly call it that, since the PHP community often uses "(associative) array" for this concept). That's an "**object**" in JS jargon, i.e., a **key-value** data structure (whereas in JS, arrays are numerically indexed). Specifically, the left-hand side is a new feature called "**destructuring arguments**", which takes an object and pulls out specific keys into local variables. On the right-hand side, there's an **object literal**, creating a new object based on local data (note that the value is omitted, a trick possible in recent JS).
3. Presumably because `connect` expects a **callback** as the first argument, and would break if you passed a non-function. Also, note that this isn't plain passthrough; it strips every key except `lanes` from the first argument, before returning it.
4. Since (1) is right, no answer needed here.

5 & 6: These are a bit broad. I'd recommend asking a new question or checking [MDN's page on arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) if you want to find out all there is to know. To answer for this specific case: the `()` on the argument is needed because the arguments are more complex than a single identifier, the `{}` in the arguments are for destructuring, the `()` on the body is to distinguish between an object literal and a block consisting only of the single statement `lanes`, and the `{}` in the body creates an object literal.

If you're wondering exactly what the (somewhat densely-coded) arrow function does, by the way, it does roughly the same thing as the following (give or take a few currently-irrelevant quirks of arrow functions):

```
function(obj) {
    return { lanes: obj.lanes };
}
```

Comment: So if lanes on the LHS is { name:"abc", age: 20} , lanes on the RHS would be {name:null,age:null} ?Is the lanes on RHS enclosed in { } to specify it's an object literal with no values? Also,  "it strips every key except lanes from the first argument, before returning it"  why would we think about lanes being stripped as a key otherwise, it isn't a key of the object but the object itself,right?

Comment: If you assign this arrow function to a variable, say `callback`, and then call `callback({lanes: {name:"abc", age: 20}, other:"stuff"})`, the return value from that would be a new object looking like `{lanes: {name:"abc", age:20}}`. The right-hand side uses `{}` to indicate that it's an object literal. An older syntax for that would be `{lanes: lanes}`, but you can omit part of that in modern JS (*only* if the key is the same as a locally-accessible variable which you wish to use as the value).

Comment: As for "why [...], it isn't a key of the object but the object itself,right?" - except it *is* a key of the object, and is *not* the object itself ;). I'll edit the answer to provide a translation from this arrow function into more-explicit JS, hopefully that will help to explain.

Comment: So, if obj which in my case is lanes had a key named lanes i.e., var lanes = { name:"abc", age: 20,lanes:5 } then the return value is {lanes:5} and if it didn't have a key named lanes it would return {lanes:undefined}

Comment: Correct, the arrow function returns `{lanes:5}` in the first case, and `{lanes:undefined}` in the second case. Also, it might be worth noting that the argument probably(?) isn't `var lanes = ...`, since it's usually odd (though not impossible) to see the same word used as a variable name and a key inside the object that variable points to. But, that detail doesn't impact the actual operation of the code (although it might affect how easy it is to reason about the code).

Comment: One last question, using ({lanes}) => (lanes) in my browser console actually gives me the value of lanes.lanes which is 5 so enclosing lanes in { } is to say that lanes has to be a key in the return object whose value is the value of the key named lanes in the parameter passed to the function and not the returned value itself?

Comment: `({lanes}) => (lanes)` (right-hand parentheses optional) returns the value that you destructured from the passed-in arguments. `({lanes}) => ({lanes})` (right-hand parentheses required) returns a new object based on the value that you destructured, using the shorthand notation that I mentioned. So yes, the `{}` on the right-hand side is used to create an object rather than just returning the extracted value directly.